# Adding multiple inputs to ListView in different forms - C#

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to add multiple inputs to a listview through TextBoxes. This is being done in different forms so I don't know how to access ListView from Form1:

This is what I've done in Form2 and this is basically all the code I got:

```
private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
        item.SubItems.Add(inputName.Text);
        item.SubItems.Add(inputAge.Text);
        item.SubItems.Add(inputBreed.Text);
        item.SubItems.Add(inputFood.Text);
    }
```

How can I access the ListView from Form2 in order to add the input from TextBox?

Answer (score 0):

You should make it a public field and access directly from within Form1

So in Form2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
         public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ListView MyListView
        {
            get { return ListViewFromThisForm; }
        }
    }
```

Where ListViewFromThisForm is whatever you added to your Controls in this form.

Then in Form1 you can just refer to an instance of Form2 and its ListView

...

```
//in Form1
var form2 = new Form2();
form2.MyListView //now accessible
```